# What does the term Clang TOT refer to?

Tags: clang

I wanted to try out some new features in Clang, and I was referred to `Clang TOT`.

Now this might be an obvious question by what the heck is `Clang TOT`.

TOT must be some acronym that I am not familiar with.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe means "top of (the) tree", as in the latest code in a source code repository.

Comment: I would go for the latter if I were them! :) Figured it was something like that. Just never seen it before.

Comment: It's not common, but for whatever reason in the LLVM and related projects it's conventional to call it that.

Comment: A lot of the LLVM developers work at Apple, and when I was at Apple, TOT was used pretty consistently as @martin describes.  Just local flavour, I guess!